# Function: Add link to / inside div

Tags: plugin-development

I'm looking to create a function that will add a link to a div (or replace the div with the div and a link - in simple; I'm trying to create a plugin that will turn the header image into a clickable link without a code edit).

Maybe I'm going about this wrong but the path I chose was str_replace. I was hoping something like this would work:

```
$content = str_replace('<div class="header-object">', '<div class="header-object"><a href=”<?php bloginfo(‘siteurl’); ?>”></a>, '<div class="header-object">';
```

The image is called through the "header-object" css class. So that's the entire div minus the end call. This code doesn't even come close to working (even as a header.php code edit). Any thoughts?

Comment: Please read my updated answer carefully, hopefully it will work for you. It's a lot but it's good to understand it before you try and implement it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this with jQuery? It would be a very simple, here's a sample, provided you have a means to get the blog's URL into the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.header-object img').wrap('<a href="#blog url here#"></a>');
});
```

This will wrap `<a>` tags around an image inside the `.header-object` class.

To implement this into your code, it is run as a script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.header-object img').wrap('<a href="#blog url here#"></a>');
});
</script>
```

You can really put that anywhere but it's recommended you put it in the `<head>` tag. If you do put it in the head tag (and not enqueue it with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)) you could use `<?php echo home_url(); ?>` in place of `#blog url here#`.

So this is what it would look like in your PHP file inside the `<head>` tag. You will need to include jQuery as well so I added an extra `<script>` tag for that, it is absolutely needed when running any jQuery (if your theme doesn't already have jQuery loaded that is!):

> **(Read my edit below this code as well!)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.header-object img').wrap('<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>');
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="header-object">
    <img src="" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

> **EDIT**

The above is an extremely basic example to help you understand, what you need to do is use what WP already has available for you. Using `wp_enqueue_scripts` in your `functions.php` file. Assuming you are using a basic theme that does not already enqueue jQuery AND no plugins that enqueue jQuery, the following code would work.

Take the jQuery code that wraps the image in `<a>` tags and put it in a file called `anything.js` in your theme's folder, in this example it will be `themes/yourtheme/js/wrapheaderimg.js` - note that `<?php echo home_url(); ?>` will not work here because it's not a PHP file.

Second open (or create one if it doesn't exist) `functions.php` in your theme's directory, and the following code should automatically add the scripts you need inside the `<head>` tag:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts(){
    // enqueue jQuery (already included in WP)
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    // register and enqueue your custom .js file
    wp_register_script( 'wrapheaderimg', get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/wrapheaderimg.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wrapheaderimg' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Now remember that `echo home_url();` won't work in that .js file, so if you are just using this for yourself, assuming the URL will always be the same, you could hard-code it in, otherwise there's another way of doing it but ***I don't know if it is best practices***. Here it goes:

When you enqueue your scripts in your `functions.php` file, the file extension doesn't have to be `.js`, you can make it `.php` so long as your JS file has a `.php` extension and the appropriate header at the very top of the file:

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
?>
```

And then back in `functions.php` you could do something like this to pass the blog's URL to the Javascript file:

```
/* functions.php */
function my_enqueue_scripts(){
    // enqueue jQuery (already registered in WP)
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    // register and enqueue your custom .php Javascript file with blog URL as a paramater
    $blogurl = urlencode( get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'wrapheaderimg', get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/wrapheaderimg.php?url=' . $blogurl );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wrapheaderimg' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

And now back in your custom PHP Javascript file, you can access that variable with this, essentially using `echo $_REQUEST['url'];`:

```
/* js/wrapheaderimg.php */
<?php
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$blogurl = urldecode( $_REQUEST['url'] );
?>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.header-object img').wrap('<a href="<?php echo $blogurl; ?>"></a>');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should of posted that jQuery is a little out of my scope. How would I throw this in a PHP document / function?

Comment: @RobPachasa I updated my answer, let me know if you have any issues with it.

Comment: It should be mentioned that you should absolutely NOT include jQuery in your theme by pasting in a script tag, this will likely break any plugin that also uses jQuery.

Comment: Right, this is just an extremely basic example. You SHOULD use `wp_enqueue_scripts` in your `functions.php` file (which I will update my answer with an example for in a bit). Also WP already has jQuery in it so you don't need to enqueue it from the Google CDN.

Comment: Oh my, this is awesome! Thank you for all your time! I'm going to try it out right now!

Comment: @RobPachasa No problem. If it works for you go ahead and accept my answer please! Thanks. :)